# How to configure Authorize.Net webhooks

Tags: php, webhooks, authorize.net, php-curl, authorize.net-webhooks

I have configured **Authorize.net**, **accept hosted** payment method for my client requirement, where everything is happening fine, except Transaction reponse. As per Authorize.net, response comes only either of these ways, **webhooks** or **CommunicatorUrl**. CommunicatorUrl not working for my code. so, opted for webhooks. Below is my code. please, suggest me something.

**My doubts are:**

1. My Code displaying this error when calling list of available webhooks

   `{
      "status": 405,
      "reason": "Method Not Allowed",
      "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST' for given parameters.",
      "correlationId": "ff90ee25-0ba7-4006-bb1e-225ea64897e3"
    }`
2. Should i configure webhook anywhere in my Merchant Panel
3. How would i get my transaction response using webhook

   ```
     <?php
     $login_transKey = 'xxx:xxx'; //Login and Transaction Key of Authorize.net
     $jsonObj = '{
       "name": "Get WebHooks",
       "request": {
           "url": "http://localhost:81/hosted_payment_form/webhookstwo.php",
           "method": "GET",
           "header": [
               {
                   "key": "Content-Type",
                   "value": "application/json",
                   "description": ""
               },
               {
                   "key": "Authorization",
                   "value": "'.$login_transKey.'",
                   "description": ""
               }
           ],
           "body": {
               "mode": "formdata",
               "formdata": []
           },
           "description": ""
       },
       "response": []
   }';
   $jsonObj = json_encode($jsonObj);
   $url = "https://apitest.authorize.net/rest/v1/eventtypes";      
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonObj);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
   $content = curl_exec($ch);
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($content); die();
   curl_close($ch);
   ?>
   ```

Please, Let me know for more information.

Comment: You can't use localhost for your URL. Authorize.Net cannot reach it.

Comment: Might be. but i am already using "accept hosted"  in my local system, where it is executing fine by redirecting to mentioned local urls, where i kept $_REQUEST & some design. Design displaying fine. but no data is getting into $_REQUEST. Although, i have tried with uploading code to server but no result. Apart from webhooks concept, I have been through the code of "iCommunicator.html", where event-Listener is available with event called "message". but i do not know how that event "message" gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the webhook URL in authorize.net account.

Also you need to select the events in the settings page.

Please make sure that the Web-hook URL always return HTTP 200 response.
Otherwise it will be automatically changed to Inactive status.

[image]